# wavwrite with 32 bits per sample seems to overflow?

Tags: sampling, wave, octave

I am trying to generate a 32bit PCM wav file with octave, the file shall contain a single full-scale sample (0db impulse). I am getting the expected result when using 24 bits per sample:

```
>> wavwrite(1, 96000, 24, 'foo.wav');
>> wavread('foo.wav')
ans =  1.00000                          # as expected
```

However, when using 32 bits per sample, the value seems to overflow.

```
>> wavwrite(1, 96000, 32, 'foo.wav');
>> wavread('foo.wav')
ans = -1                                # WHAT ?!
```

I am expecting the second `wavread('foo.wav')` to return `1` not `-1`. I have checked the wav file with a hex editor, the sample raw value is `0x80000000`, I am expecting it to be `0x7fffffff`.
Is it an octave bug or am I missing something?

Using `0.99999` instead of `1` generates the expected result.

Comment: Check the documentation -- different bit formats have different max and min values. It's possible that for 32 bits the max is 1.0-eps.

Comment: using matlab, `audiowrite('foo.wav', 1, 96000, 'BitsPerSample', 32);` works fine... Could be a problem of representation: Q31 can't represent 1.

Comment: It sounds like an octave bug. Matlab (R2014b) produces the expected result.

Comment: [this](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?45490) could be the bug : Octave writes in 32bit int (type 1) whereas Matlab writes 32bit normalized floats (type 3)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it is a [bug](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?45490). Octave's `wavwrite()` function writes 32-bit wav in 32 bits int (type 1 format) instead of normalized 32-bit floats (type 3 format). Unfortunately, 1 can't be represented in 32-bit type 1 format which is why you get this result.

The solution could be <strike>to use the `audiowrite()` function</strike>, or to write `0x7fffffff` instead of 1.

[More](https://www.kvraudio.com/forum/archive/hardware_setup_and_system_configuration/2003-03/16334.php) about wav formats.

EDIT: seems from the bug report that the audiowrite function has the same problem...